# Can I exclude a range within a range?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to know how can I exclude a range within a range?
I have this query:

```
SELECT "FailCode",
count (*) FILTER (where "FailCode" between 10 and 43) as "Totals"
FROM minical01
group by 1;
```

but in that range of "FailCode" between 10 and 43, I would like to exclude the range of "FailCode" between 31 and 34

The following query is what I've tried, but it's not giving me good results. it's giving me 0's on all the rows in the column "Totals"

```
SELECT "FailCode",
count (*) FILTER (where ("FailCode" between 10 and 30) and ("FailCode" between 35 and 43)) as "Totals"
FROM minical01
group by 1;
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: `"FailCode"` cannot be simultaneously less than 31 **and** greater than 34. Perhaps you meant to use the **or** operator.

Comment: Maybe the or could have worked, but I still get the result of values from 32 which is in the range I want to exclude

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example via dbfiddle then.

Comment: Your query with `FILTER (where ("FailCode" between 10 and 30) or ("FailCode" between 35 and 43))` seems to have worked fine. You got 32 with a count of 0, as expected/wanted.

Comment: Please do not post images for the reasons outlined in [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/470530). Use **formatted text** for queries and results!

Comment: check this out: [help me write this query in sql.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ zeros are not the count. You can see in the first top image that I was not getting zeros for the count but once I applied the conditions I get the zeros. Zeros are not the count I am expecting.

Comment: Thanks  @mustaccio
I will avoid posting images and get familiar with dbfiddle

Comment: I wasn't talking about the first image but about the last one (where the code has OR).

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Oops my bad. Thanks so much for your hints and comment. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

> but in that range of "FailCode" between 10 and 43, I would like to exclude the range of "FailCode" between 31 and 34

I think you are looking for a NOT condition:

```
count (*) FILTER (where ("FailCode" between 10 and 43) 
                    and not ("FailCode" between 31 and 34) ) as "Totals"
```

Comment: I am still getting a "Failcode" row with a 32 value. I wonder why it's not working

Comment: It is working. If you don't want  the rows with FailCode between 31 and 34 to appear at all, put the condition in the WHERE clause, not in the FILTER.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me at first:

```
SELECT "FailCode",
SUM ("FailCode") AS total
FROM minical01
where ("FailCode" between 10 and 43) and not ("FailCode" between 31 and 34)
group by 1
order by 1;
```

But this next one worked much better for me:

```
SELECT "FailCode",
count("FailCode") AS total
FROM minical01
where ("FailCode" between 10 and 43) and not ("FailCode" between 31 and 34) 
group by 1
order by 1
```